# Chrome is not on the list of allowed programs on Windows Firewall but works fine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, firewall

I check my Firewall's list of allowed program and Google Chrome is not one of them but it still works, it can still connect to the internet.

I'm really confused. I don't know how this Firewall really works.

My OS is Windows 7 Starter

Comment: You would have had a prompt when you installed Chrome that asked if you would like to allow Chrome through Windows Firewall, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The firewall controls network communication. Applications may be white-listed or blacklisted however neither is required.

An application that does not have a listing set should be able to operate over standard ports, such as Chrome. Adding these to a whitelist is sometimes a good idea as other policies / applications might block apps that are not explicitly whitelisted.

This is sort of [mentioned here](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/windows_os_security/To-Whitelist-or-To-Not-Whitelist.html) for example: